# is it possible to integrate my plugin inside google calendar?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api-client, google-calendar-api, google-gadget

I would like to customise Google calendar by adding an extra feature. How I should approach this? For example, I would like to add extra options while creating a calendar event.

Comment: Try to look in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) if the option you are looking for is existing.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Hi thanks for your comment. I checked the documentation and there is no clue for my requirement. Please see this question this is my requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787956/how-to-add-a-custom-button-inside-google-calendar and tell me whether it is possible in Google Calendar