# How to add a custom button inside Google Calendar?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-gadget

[image: I want to have custom button as shown in the image]

Is it possible to have the feature in the image  inside Google Calendar. I came across Gadget in Google Calendar,  but I cannot figure out how to do it. Is there any way Google is allowing to add add-ons for calendar?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. What you can do is create your own interface/client-side UI and then use the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) to perform operations. You can also give the [Calendar Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) if it suits your purpose.